# React Native + Redux: How to subscribe to changes in state?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a component and I want to call a method checking the state whenever it changes. This is my component with a dummy method to demonstrate what I want to do (animate the view offscreen if `onboarding.show === false`):

```
export class Onboarding extends Component {

  animateView() {
    // i want to call this method when 
    // the state changes
    // something like;
    if (!this.props.onboarding.show) {
      Animated.spring(...);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { onboarding, finish } = this.props; 

    return (
      <Animated.View>
        ...
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

...

export default connect(
  state => {
    return {
      onboarding: state.onboarding,
    };
  },
  dispatch => {
    return {
    };
  }
)(Onboarding);
```

Is there a way to subscribe to the changes in state?

== UPDATE ==

as requested, here's what my slideOffScreen method does:

```
  slideOffScreen() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.offsetX, {
      toValue: -Dimensions.get('window').width,
      duration: 350,
      easing: Easing.elastic(),
    }).start();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The react-redux `connect` method wraps the component with a container component that is aware of the store's state changes. Whenever the state changes, `connect` re-renders the wrapped component (Onboarding in your case).

According to the [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components):

> Technically, a container component is just a React component that uses
>   store.subscribe() to read a part of the Redux state tree and supply
>   props to a presentational component it renders. You could write a
>   container component by hand, but we suggest instead generating
>   container components with the React Redux library's connect()
>   function, which provides many useful optimizations to prevent
>   unnecessary re-renders.

If your component doesn't re-rendered when the state changes, check if you're not mutating the state instead of replacing it. Redux checks if the state changed by shallowly comparing the old state, and the new state (comparing only the references, and not the values).

For example, to add an item to an array, you can't use `array.push(item)` because that won't create a new array, just mutate the existing one. Instead you'll have to use something like `array.concat(item)`, which does.

To update objects, you can see in the redux docs under [handling actios](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions) example, you can see that to create a new state:

> We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with Object.assign().
>   Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter }) is also
>   wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty
>   object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread
>   operator proposal to write { ...state, ...newState } instead.

Comment: I think I found the answer using `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: You're component is re-rendered whenever the store's status changes - you can do the the same thing in render.

Comment: Can you supply more info about the `slideOffScreen` method?

Comment: Yep it just animates the full screen view so that it slides off the screen. I updated my question with the code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if (!props.onboarding.show) {
      this.slideOffScreen();
    }
  }
```

not sure if there's a way to do it through the redux API